# Derivative of expression involving a left-invariant connection

Tags: lie-groups, connections

I'm trying to understand a calculation done in [this](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4893357) paper. Somewhat simplified, the setup is as follows.

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $\varrho$ its Lie algebra.

Let $\nabla$ be a left-invariant connection, which means that $\nabla$ evaluated in two left-invariant vector fields is itself a left-invariant vector field.

They then calculate;

$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \nabla_{u(t)}{u(t)} = \nabla_{\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} u(t)}{u(0)} +\nabla_{u(0)}{\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} u(t)}$$

Any suggestions as to why this holds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\nabla$ is bilinear

Comment: Perfect, thank you!